# Define generic parameter that should be a Product/Tuple (any size) of String components

Tags: scala, generics

Something like this

```
trait SomeTrait {
  def m[A <: (String, ... *)](value: A)
}
```

Probably, it's achievable using some libraries.

Update: List(String) looks like a straightforward alternative, but I'm curious about ability to express such condition.

Comment: Tuples of different lengths are different types that are (almost) unrelated. Enter this into the REPL, `List((1,2),(2,3,4))`, and it will tell you that the result is type `List[Product with Serializable]`. In other words, its just about as useless as `List[Any]`.

Comment: @jwvh It can be significantly more useful than `Any` in certain circumstances, for example, `Product` provides a few methods that are really nice for type-agnostic pretty-printing of large tree-like data structures built up from case classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shapeless.

```
import shapeless._

trait SomeTrait {
 def m[T <: Product, L <: HList](t : T)
                    (implicit gen: Generic.Aux[T, L],
                              c: LUBConstraint[L, String]) =  println(t)
}


// m(("2","3","7")) // compiles
// m(("2","3",7)) // wont compile
// m(("2","3","7","8")) // compiles
```